# Script for Dual boot

Tags: server, scripts

I am running file server in ubuntu server with dual boot with windows 7 now i want SCRIPT that can restart the server at the midnight and start to windows 7 and i have put some customise script in my windows 7 so that it can execute at night from windows 7 and again in the morning when i start the server it will automatically start with ubuntu server

Kindly guide me to execute it via script

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution you should be able to work with. It isn't pretty and takes a bit of work and may be different depending on what version of Ubuntu you are using. I came up with this using 16.04. I also just tested this to boot into a different kernel because I don't have Windows installed on this box. 
Since you have a dual boot I have to assume that you already have a grub menu showing and hopefully a Windows entry in the main menu not in a sub menu as I will get into later.

First you need to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file

Look for the entry `GRUB_DEFAULT="#"` it probably is 0. Change it to read `GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"` add a line under it that says `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"`

It should look like the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
...and so on...
```

Save the file and in a terminal run `sudo update-grub`

Now comes the part I'm guessing at. When you boot the computer and its at the GRUB menu ... On my VM box that I used to test this shows the following entries

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+,serial console)
Test1
```

I had to create the `Test1 entry` for this to work but I have a feeling that you have a `Windows entry` somewhere on this list but I don't know where it falls. You need to count where that menu item falls in the list. For example if your `Windows entry` is where my `Test1 entry` is then it would be in position 4 (Ubuntu is in position 0 not 1)

Now that we have that we need to create a file .. I will use `startwin` in this example
open `startwin` in your favorite editor and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
grub-reboot 4 
reboot now
```

(of course 4 being whatever number you determined that your `Windows entry` is positioned) save the file and open terminal. Change to the directory where `startwin` is located and make sure its set to be executable.

```
sudo chmod +x startwin
```

Now you are ready to try it out.. open terminal change to the directory the file is located and type `sudo ./startwin` of course save all your work and close anything open because this will restart the computer. It should start in Windows and when you tell Windows to reboot it should go back to Ubuntu again.

If it worked all you have to do is set up a cron job to have it run at midnight.

Edit `/etc/crontab` add the entry at the bottom

```
00 00 * * * root path/to/startwin/startwin
```

and make a Windows task to reboot when you want it to switch back to Ubuntu like 7am.

Now at 7am your Windows Task would automatically reboot into Ubuntu and at midnight your Ubuntu script would automatically reboot into Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Orion it works like charm exactly what i want